# MVC4 model binding when table row has been removed from DOM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, model-binding

I have an MVC4 action which returns a partial view of a table, which is populated by a collection on the `Model`. Adding to this collection is done using an AJAX request to a controller action called `AddItem(Model model)`.

I have a client side javascript method which removes a row from the table when the user clicks a button on that row (based loosely upon [this blog entry](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)):

```
function removeLine(button) {
    $(button).closest("tr").remove();
}
```

This removes the row in the view, however if I have 5 rows and I remove the second row only the first row is bound to the model when I post back to an action - the collection property will contain up until the index which was removed and ignore any subsequent items.

I gather this is because the index jumps from 0 to 2, and as such doesn't think there are any more items to be bound into the model from the form data.

How do I ensure that the items after the row which was removed are bound back to the model?

Comment: You're right. The index must be zero-based and unbroken. This will help you: http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/

Comment: Thanks ataravati - I used that method and it is now working.

Comment: 6 years later and I'm working an old MVC app and I'm facing the same problem. Unfortunately I can't introduce guids so am having to manipulate the table rows in javascript to ensure they have the correct numbering :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, in the comments @ataravati suggested a [different method](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/).
I ended up going with this method as it introduces a guid indexing system which the model binder understands.